Stop motion possible claymation film from last 1980s early 1990s Moon Sun Hill snail? Fable
Does anyone remember the name of a short film or maybe it was a tv program from the early 1990s or late 1980s ,
I think it was a program depicting fables, I used to watch it on a video tape, in the UK although it may not have been British.
Basically all I can remember is a sun setting over a small round hill and there is possibly a snail climbing up the hill.
Also I think there may have been a rock on the top of the hill which talked.
It is quite a dark scene, and I think the sun sets and has a face and then maybe the moon comes up over this little rounded hill.
Such a vague memory, but I know if I see it I will remember it immediately!
If anyone has any ideas of what it might be I would really appreciate it as it has been bugging me for years! 

I know this is a long shot that only loosely connects the things you've mentioned, but I also interpret from your description that you are recalling a very distant and vague memory.
Could it be The Nightmare Before Christmas? 
This is a video of the scene which contains the hill (and most things you mentioned) that I think you might be referencing.

It is a stop motion film from the early 90's (1993 if I recall correctly)
Although the movie is not British, the characters do speak UK English.
The movies focuses on "holiday worlds": Halloween town, Christmas town, Easter town, ... where all the residents are thematically linked to their own holiday. You mention "fables", but maybe you are remembering thematic characters that fit their holiday.
One of the most iconic places in the movie is a hill that has a spiral:



As most scenes occur in Halloween town, it is a very dark setting. Although I do not remember the sun coming up behind this hill, the moon is often in the background.
You mention a snail, maybe you are remembering the spiral pattern, which matches the pattern of a snail's shell?
During the scene on the hill, Jack (the main character) walks down the hill, which unfolds its spiral to make a walkway for Jack. You can see this in the video I linked, around the 3:25 mark. Instead of a snail that crawls up the hill, could you be remembering the hill unfurling its spiral to let someone walk down it slowly?
You mention a talking rock. There's no talking rock as far as I remember. But the pumpkins (visible in the bottom left of the above picture) are alive (they are talking heads), which is shown at some point during the movie.
Another possible explanation for the talking rock: in the scene on the hill, Jack takes off his hown head while reciting Shakespeare:



A third possible explanation for your talking rock (but a really long shot), Jack's dog Zero emerges from a gravestone (in the shape of a doghouse):



Thank you for your thorough reply, I really do appreciate it, but unfortunately it's not the nightmare before christmas, as much as I did used to love watching it as a child! I think it was something much less mainstream as I have been trying to find it for years, witj not luck, so thought I would try on here. Thank you again

Claymation Comedy of Horrors Show (1991)
Its the only movie I could find that fits your description. :)

Wilshire Pig and Sheldon Snail discover a map to uncover Doctor Frankenswine's monster. All kinds of mishaps ensue in their quest.

Well, I could not find the exact moment you described, but it fits your specifications:

1991
Has a snail
It's a claymation

Is this your snail?

